# Mark usernames contains a specific name using regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a usernames.txt full of random usernames.

Example file: http://autoigs.com/example_usernames.rar

I want to bookmark a usernames that contains a specific names.

Example: mark usernames contain name "Michael".

and copy the bookmarked to export the marked usernames to another textfile.

What am doing is manually using notepad++ Ctrl+F then mark, Then i bookmark the line then mark all.

But this work only to find one name.

So I just wonder.. is it possible to use regex to bookmark multi names in one time?

Example: I want to bookmark usernames that contain the names: Joshua, Michael, Rooger, David, etc?

I wish somebody can help me. thank you.
regards.

Comment: Use a regex with alternation: `(Joshua|Michael|Rooger|David)` and then go to *Mark* -> *Mark all* with *Bookmark line* checked.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "mark the username"? Mark with what? In the usernames.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

@mzaboss, Wiktor Stribiżew wanted to describe what you are going to do in notepad++:

[image]